# Longest path with N steps in matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, depth-first-search, backtracking

I'm trying to find a simple path of length N in a RxC matrix, given a starting cell. The path should follow a restriction, given by a boolean function. The goal is to later use this to find the longest path in the matrix.

I got a solution set up, however I don't know how to modify it to know when a solution does not exist.

My solution consists of a DFS approach using backtracking. The solution is correct when there is one, but the program returns the longest path found instead of saying such path doesn't exist.

I know there are similar problems with solutions available but I'd like to understand where my logic is failing.

Here's the code (from a cell we can move in all 8 directions):

```
Bool DFS(Map *map,Point* srcPt,short steps,Bool (*restrictionCompare)(Point *p1, Point *p2))
{
    Point *target;
    short row = getPointRow(srcPt);
    short col = getPointCol(srcPt);

    // Found N-steps path!
    if (steps == 0)
    {
        puts("Path found!\n");
        return 1;
    }


    //Mark the M[row][col] as visited
    markAsVisited(map,row,col);


    // Iterate over all 8 directions of a cell
    for (short i = 0; i < DIRECTIONS; ++i)
    {
        short coords[2];
        // Get a valid adjacent cell
        if (getNeighbour(map,srcPt,i,coords,restrictionCompare) == FALSE) continue;

        target = getMapPoint(map,coords[0],coords[1]); // This is the valid neighbour


        //if cell wasn't visited before...
        if (isVisited(target) == FALSE)
        {

            // ..recursively call DFS from cell
            if(DFS(map,target,--steps,restrictionCompare) == TRUE)
            {

                // Show point
                showPoint(target);

                return TRUE;
            }                     
        }

    }

    // Backtrack
    markAsUnvisited(map,row,col);
    return FALSE;
}
```

An example of path of length found by the program:

[image: path]

Any suggestions on how to improve the code's efficiency is also welcome.

Comment: The code you've shown looks like it could work. But there's lots of code missing that might not work. See [mcve].

Comment: Well most of the functions are encapsulation of matrix operations, only getNeighbour function is not